# Add an extra tag or element in Soap Response using Jaxws

Tags: java, soap, cxf, jax-ws

I am developing one soap service using Spring-Cxf. here I have my response structure as below

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "response", propOrder = {
    "name",
    "addressList"
})
public class Response 
{

private String name;
private List<Address> addressList;
}

-- getter and setter follows
```

The current response is coming like

```
<response>
   <name>RASSI ANDREA</name>
   <addressList type="1">
      <address>Address 1</address>
      <address>Address 2</address>
      <address>Address 3</address>
   </addressList>
   <addressList type="2">
      <address>Address 4</address>
      <address>Address 5</address>
      <address>Address 6</address>
   </addressList>
</response>
```

But the actual response structure I need is below where a new tag 'row' is added.

```
<response>
   <name>RASSI ANDREA</name>
   <row>
      <addressList type="1">
         <address>Address 1</address>
         <address>Address 2</address>
         <address>Address 3</address>
      </addressList>
   </row>
   <row>
      <addressList type="2">
         <address>Address 4</address>
         <address>Address 5</address>
         <address>Address 6</address>
      </addressList>
   </row>
</response>
```

Can anyone explain me where should I make the change to achieve this ? Any change in annotation or Creating a new class as 'row'( though this will a bad approach I guess)

Comment: Why are you doing this? The additional element should be in the WSDL, and your code should be autogenerated. So the procedure should be: 1. add the element to the WSDL, 2. Regenerate the code, 3. change your implementation, and 4. Notify all clients of the WSDL change. And maybe 4. should really be first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the Annotation `@XmlElementWrapper(name="row")` to your `addressList` will add the `<row>` tag to your XML. Give it a try.

You will need to add the following statement:

> **import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;**

```
public class Response {

    private String name;
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="row") // Add this line here
    private List<Address> addressList;
}
```

Comment: this approach works for the example I mentioned. But what if there are multiple properties before the new tag.. example <response>
  <response>
   <row>
      <addressList type="1">
         <address>Address 1</address>
      </addressList><name>my name1</name>
   </row>
   <row>
      <addressList type="2">
         <address>Address 4</address>
      </addressList><name>my name2</name>
   </row>
</response>    where there are multiple properties under the new tag which is added then this aparoach is not working